# how to change initial login command of zsh

Tags: authentication, terminal, command, zsh

have installed zsh while it not the original terminal of macOS, and followed some online step to make it be the default terminal at that time with some other shell like iterm2 on macOS.
now it always login to the admin user that time I set, which already deleted and now my macOs only one admin user which is not that login user, I checked everywhere could find how to change that command to help me switch the initial login to the current user I use.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN7Yg.png)

Comment: I don't understand the question. For instance, what is the meaning of the sentence _it always login to the admin user_? A shell does not "login as a user". What I wonder,is why you run the shell with the `-p` option (privileged), and what the `-f jimmy` is supposed to do. What speaks against running it with just `zsh -l`? Also, it would be helpful if you tell us which terminal and what MacOS version you are using. The preferences dialogue on my `Terminal.app` looks very different from that in your screenshot.

Comment: Aside from this, the question is not about programming, and you likely get better responses when posting it at [apple.se].

Comment: @user1934428 The image actually is from `Terminal.app`. From the **Shell** menu, choose **Show Inspector**.

Comment: @JonathanDodds : Must be a different version of Terminal.app then. When I go to Profiles/Shell (there is no other "Shell menu"), I don't see a _Show Inspector_. Using Terminal 2.12.7 on MacOS Monterey.

Comment: The 'Shell' menu is in the menu bar - the menus are <Apple Menu>, Terminal, **Shell**, Edit, View, Window, Help.